# images not showing on image slider

Tags: jquery, html, image, flexslider

I am using a simple image slider which works fine on localhost, but now I have deployed the site, and it is not showing the images online.

Showing this error on browser console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

The URL for my site is: http://the-kings-arms.co.uk

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Comment: Where are your files located on your server? We need more information about them in order to diagnose your issue

Comment: either (1) you are missing the images online or (2) you are using a wrong path to them. nothing more.

Comment: The images are located in the images folder, where all the others are.

Comment: <div id="slider2" class="container_12">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <li>
        <img src="images/k1.jpg"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="images/k5.jpg"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="images/k2.jpg"/>
        </li>
                    <li>
        <img src="images/k4.jpg"/>
        </li>
                    <li>
        <img src="images/k3.jpg"/>
        </li>
                    </ul>
             </div>

Comment: you have to upload the images to the server.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, it is now working, i simply re-named all the images, and then uploaded the site again.

Answer (score 2):

Your images don't exist on your server. You can see this by directly navigating to 
http://the-kings-arms.co.uk/images/k1.jpg

You will see a 404 error. Try to upload them again.

Compare this to ones that do work, like the following:
http://the-kings-arms.co.uk/images/eating.png

Comment: they are there, i have just checked the file manager of the site and they are in the images folder, so strange

Comment: Shall i try putting them in a separate images folder, will this help?